# Getting Windows Version from Preprocessor (C++ Win32)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c-preprocessor

I'm working on a Win32 application and am currently trying to implement multi-display features. For this, I want to use `EnumDisplayMonitors`, a feature that is only present in Windows 2000-upwards. I've done my best to maintain backwards compatibility up to Windows 95 thus far.

I want to, therefore, ignore this related section of code when the program runs on older versions of Windows. However, its mere presence anywhere in the code, even if it's not executed, crashes the program. I want to use `#ifdef` to ignore this section of code, however I can't seem to figure out a way to get the current Windows version from the Preprocessor. I've seen suggestions to use `WINVER` or `_WIN32_WINNT` but both need to be set by me as far as I can understand, defeating the whole point. Any attempts to use them predictably did not work as intended.

Is there a way to get the current version of Windows from the preprocessor? If not, is there another way to disable this function completely depending on the OS? Again, regardless whether it's used, its mere presence crashes on Windows 95.

Comment: Your question is fundamentally misconceived. The preprocessor runs at compile time, and you need to select your code at runtime, based on the Windows version you are executing on, not the Windows version you compiled on.

Comment: *Again, regardless whether it's used, its mere presence crashes on Windows 95.* At a massive inconvenience to all negative three Windows 95 users??

Comment: @ta.speot.is +1 Targeting anything less than Windows 7 is pointless in 2020.

Comment: Sadly there are <expletive deleted> tons of Windows XP boxes out there.

Comment: It doesn't crash. The process simply doesn't get off the ground, because imports cannot be resolved. This is how compile-time dynamic linking works, unless you are using delay-loading. I don't know whether delay-loading is supported on Windows 95, though. Might have to go with manual runtime dynamic linking. The module is user32.dll - you'll have a lot of imports to resolve.

Comment: @IInspectable "*I don't know whether delay-loading is supported on Windows 95, though*" - delay-loading is a feature of the compiler, linker and runtime framework, not of the OS. Delay-loading is just a software wrapper around the Win32 API `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions, which do exist on Win95. So if your toolchain does not implement support for delay-loading, you can just call those functions manually in your own code.

Comment: Why are you bothered about Windows 95?  Or even Windows 2000 for that matter.  AFAIK, nobody runs either of these anymore.

Comment: @PaulSanders that you know of. Who says nobody is at all? There are plenty of industries that stay with old hardware and OSes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nevertheless, it's worth asking the question.  If the app is for commercial distribution, then supporting these operating systems is pointless.

Comment: @rem: Correct, and part of the implementation is distributed as compiled object code. That object code needs be compatible with the target OS. I don't know if there is any distribution that does in fact support Windows 95, although delay-loading apparently was introduced in Visual C++ 6, so that seems plausible.

Comment: @IInspectable Visual Studio is not the only C++ compiler that implements delay-loading

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to handle this is not with the preprocessor at all. You need to use the Win32 API [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) function at runtime instead, eg:

```cpp
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_EDM)(HDC, LPCRECT, MONITORENUMPROC, LPARAM);
LPFN_EDM lpEnumDisplayMonitors = (LPFN_EDM) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("user32.dll"), "EnumDisplayMonitors");
if (lpEnumDisplayMonitors)
{
    // use lpEnumDisplayMonitors as needed... 
}
else
{
    // use something else...
}
```

This is even described in Microsoft's documentation:

[Operating System Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version)

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present. This is because the operating system may have had new features added in a redistributable DLL. Rather than using the Version API Helper functions to determine the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence of the feature itself.
>
> To determine the best way to test for a feature, refer to the documentation for the feature of interest. The following list discusses some common techniques for feature detection:
>
> - You can test for the presence of the functions associated with a feature. To test for the presence of a function in a system DLL, call the `LoadLibrary` function to load the DLL. Then call the `GetProcAddress` function to determine whether the function of interest is present in the DLL. Use the pointer returned by `GetProcAddress` to call the function. Note that even if the function is present, it may be a stub that just returns an error code such as `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`.
> - You can determine the presence of some features by using the [`GetSystemMetrics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) function. For example, you can detect multiple display monitors by calling `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)`. There are several versions of the redistributable DLLs that implement shell and common control features. For information about determining which versions are present on the system your application is running on, see the topic [Shell and Common Controls Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Bb776779(v=VS.85).aspx).

If your compiler toolchain supports [Delay Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019), then you can use that instead of calling `GetProcAddress()` manually. Set your project to delay-load  `user32.dll` and then call `EnumDisplayMonitors()` normally after first validating the OS supports what you need, such as checking if Windows is Win2K or later via [`GetVersionEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa), or checking if multiple monitors are installed, eg:

```cpp
OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
GetVersionEx(&osvi);

if (osvi.dwMajorVersion >= 5) // Win2K = 5.0
{
    // use EnumDisplayMonitors as needed... 
}
else
{
    // use something else...
}
```

```cpp
if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS) > 1)
{
    // use EnumDisplayMonitors as needed... 
}
else
{
    // use something else...
}
```

Comment: Why use circumstantial evidence rather than established facts in deciding whether to call an API function? Don't call it if it's not there. That's what the first bullet point in your quote suggests, for good reasons: It does indeed implement what you're after, will automatically adjust to features getting backported, and is immune to the OS not being honest about its true version.

Answer (score 1):

Compile targeting the lowest Windows you support with `WINVER`/`_WIN32_WINNT` (whatever your SDK supports), then load whatever functions you need dynamically at runtime (`LoadLibrary` etc.) after knowing where you are actually running.

Comment: I don't think `_WIN32_WINNT` goes back any further than ... Windows NT. The question is about Windows 95.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah, but since OP themselves have referred to `_WIN32_WINNT`, I assume they are compiling using a non-ancient SDK.

Comment: They are also stating `WINVER`. `WINVER` is the pre-NT preprocessor symbol. Regardless, that doesn't solve the issue. Because now they cannot use `EnumDisplayMonitors` on any system.

Comment: @IInspectable They can use `EnumDisplayMonitors` wherever the DLL is found. Dynamically loading it is the way to ensure backwards compatibility, and it does solve the issue at hand, so I am not sure what you are referring to. You even said it yourself in a comment above (!).

Comment: @IInspectable On the `WINVER` part, I edited the answer.